# Session is new when using httpsession and called by AJAX

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using httpsession to save object cart. If I access the page normally, Spring MVC uses the current session, which is fine.

The problem is that I use AJAX to call the action in the controller and Spring MVC to create a new session. Attributes in the session are removed:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product/cart/add", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Integer addItemToCart(@RequestBody ProductDTO product, HttpSession session){
    logger.info(session.isNew());
    CartDTO cart = (CartDTO) session.getAttribute("CART");
    if(cart == null){
        cart = new CartDTO();
    }
    cart.addItem(product, 1);
    session.setAttribute("CART", cart);
    logger.info(cart.toString());
    return cart.getCart().size();
}
```

I tried to find what causes this, but haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Please paste your code as a text not image.

Comment: I have updated code. session.isNew() is always true. How to get current session? please. thank you